# Converting mysqlpp::String to C++ int

Tags: c++, sql, mysql, visual-studio, mysqlpp

Ok, I'm relatively new to using the mysqlpp library that is used in Visual Studio to connect to a MySQL database and am having trouble trying to convert a vector of type mysqlpp::String to a vector of type int. Does anyone have any experience with mysqlpp and would mind helping me out a little? I've posted an example of what I'm basically trying to do below that appears in my code. Assume the vector futureItemsets is already populated and I just want to copy over the contents into an integer vector. Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
vector<int> timeFrameItemsets;
vector<mysqlpp::String> futureItemsets;

for(int j = 0; j < static_cast<int>(futureItemsets.size()); j++) {
timeFrameItemsets.push_back(futureItemsets[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysqlpp::String has `operator int()` so your code snippet should work.  What problem are you having with it?

If you want to be more explicit, you can use mysqlpp::String's [conv](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/refman/classmysqlpp_1_1String.html#a12) function:

```
int i = futureItemsets[j].conv<int>(0);
timeFrameItemsets.push_back(i);
```